# Convertir string en numero decimal

Tags: python

Buenas noches,

Estoy teniendo problemas al convertir el siguiente string en un numero decimal.
Extraigo el numero desde una web y este viene con . en vez de con ,
Al intentar substituir el . por la , el resultado es el siguiente:

```
x = ,,,,,
```

reemplaza todos los dígitos y no solo el punto.

Este es mi código:

```
x = "18.58"
if "." in x:
    x = re.sub(".", ",", x)

if x == float:
    x = round(x)
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Un saludo,

Comment: El cararacter "." es un subString, solo debes buscarlo y reemplazarlo por el ",".

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que el caracter "." (Dot) por defecto en regex **captura cualquier carácter menos el de nueva linea**. Debes escaparlo para que solo capture literalmente el caracter ".":

```
x = "18.58"
x = re.sub("\.", ",", x)
```

El condicional previo es innecesario.

También puedes usar `str.replace`:

```
x = "18.58"
x = x.replace(".", ",")
```

No obstante, no puedes convertir un string con la coma a float en Python, el separador decimal es el punto de hecho.

Para pasar a float solo necesitas aplicar el casting:

```
>>> x = "18.58"
>>> x= float(x)
>>> x
18.58
>>> x = round(x)
>>> x
19
```

Si lo que recibes es un string que es un float (o un entero) con el punto como separador decimal (que no separador de miles) puedes hacer lo que pretendes simplemente con:

```
x = "18.58"
x = round(float(x))
```

Comment: Pensaba que el error al intentar convertir el string a float venia del (Dot). Me faltaba convertirlo a float x = round(float(x)). Muchas gracias por la explicación FJSevilla

Comment: @XavierVillafaina no, el punto es correcto. He editado la respuesta. Cuando si da problemas es cuando se usa como separador de miles: "1.005.545" por ejemplo si da problemas en el casting.